# RadiPanel DJ Panel Infractions Error

Tags: php, mysql

I need infractions on my panel, but I get an error on the installation file `/staff/_res/infraction/install.php`. I click on submit and I get this error:

```
MySQL Error: Duplicate column name 'totalInfractions'
```

On the `PHPMYADMIN`, it says:

```
#1060 - Duplicate column name 'totalInfractions'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

`Duplicate column name` means that a `SELECT` query returned twice the same column (something like `SELECT id, id`). Post some code so that we can analyse it (exactly, the SQL queries you're sending).